# Has God ever commanded or instructed anything that He himself did not also satisfy?

Tags: life-of-jesus, commandments, divine-law

This obviously includes the 10 commandments and the instructions He gave to Israel, but also includes the things he lead his Holy Spirit to direct the prophets and apostles to say and what he directed Jesus to say and do (since Jesus only ever spoke as God the Father directed Him).

Comment: Maybe if you think he did then you should ask a question on that specific thing.

Comment: I don't understand your question. God commanded Noah to build an Ark. God never built an Ark. God commanded Joshua to march on Jericho. God never marched on Jericho. God commanded the Israelites to collect mana. God never collected mana.

Comment: I didn't say he "did" everything I said "satisfy" everything. I satisfy many laws by simply not breaking them (Also, God did build an Ark). I was asking if He ever did something that violated or failed to "satisfy" one of his own instructions or commands.

Comment: If the instruction is "Build an ark," then not building the ark violates the instructions.

Comment: Yes, *if the instruction was not specific to Noah*. God not building an Ark doesn't violate it because he never commanded himself to build it.

Comment: So you've changed the "rules now"... now the question is "Did God ever command himself to do something which he didn't do?"?

Comment: No, the question is "Has God ever commanded or instructed anything that He himself did not also **satisfy?**" Love your enemies is satisfied by God since He keeps that command (since it is part of his character). Build an Ark is satisfied by God because he told Noah to do it. Yet even that is a picture of God delivering men who trust him. In either of these cases he does not act against those instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think there are a few, given the nature of His position of authority over all creation. However, the question would be answered differently if you are referring to God as the Godhead (ie, the Trinity) or just as God the Father.

If you are just referring to God the Father, then the answer is any form of submission. God commands us to submit to the government, but He Himself does not submit to any government of man. (As we know from the New Testament, Jesus *did* submit to the government, and a sinful one, lest we forget).

The Bible tells us Jesus fulfilled the law, and never sinned (1 Peter 2:22) so therefore Jesus completely fulfilled all requirements that men had from God, so in that sense, no, God did not command anything that He (Jesus) did not Himself fulfill.

Comment: +1 I just realized this was a silly question because the bible clearly states Jesus did fulfill the whole law.

Comment: Well, it was a better question than you think, (and others give you credit for) since you didn't only say "the law" but also "instructions", and it serves to illustrate how the Trinity operates to some extent, and how even being God, He can still  set the example for us to follow, something not present in many other belief systems. We can learn how to submit as sons from the Son of God, and how to be fathers from God the Father, for example. And importantly, He also sets the example that we must submit even to sinful governments, something some people seem to think we don't have to do.